# A tool like JSONLint.com for XML

Tags: xml, json, jsonlint

I use JSONLint.com to help me quickly turn JSON dumps into something readable and right now I am dealing with some hefty ever-changing XML that I'd love to be able to read easier. Does anyone know of a tool like JSONLint for XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking for formatting, rather than validation, you can use http://xmlbeautifier.com/

Comment: This should do just fine! Thanks.

Comment: doesn't work for me. but http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html is much better

Answer (score 0):

Best tool available for formatting and validating XML is http://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer